# Can you do Vector addition in Java, natively?

Tags: java, math, vector

I Know there's a "Vector" class in java, but it seems to be just a simpler ArrayList type of deal, not an actual, mathematical Vector (as in a magnitude and a direction).

Is there any way to do Vector manipulations (particularly addition) in Java? Or am I stuck on my own having to implement it or use a third party module?

Comment: fyi, a vector is a thread-safe arraylist

Comment: Snarky answer = write a JNI interface to SIMD

Comment: I've written a fast open source library for mathematical vectors that may meet your needs: https://github.com/mikera/vectorz

Comment: i am using http://toxiclibs.org/ for all my 2D/3D vector calculations. it's created for Processing but can be used in other projects also.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, you'll have to write a class or use a library such as [JScience](http://jscience.org/api/org/jscience/mathematics/vector/Vector.html)

Comment: Thanks for the link, JScience really does look great!

Comment: Although in retrospect, it confuses me greatly. It does things I've never seen before. I guess I'll make a new question about it...

Comment: Looking at the JScience website and CVS repository, it looks like nothing has changed in the past 2 years.  Not exactly a good sign ...

Answer (score 4):

If you are looking to make a vector in 2d space, couldn't you just go with a simple `Point2D(x,y)` and let the length of your vector define magnitude?

So that `Point2D a = new Point2D(1,1);` has a magnitude of 1.4, and a NE direction. And a `Point2D b = new Point2D(2,2);` has the same direction but a magnitude of 2.8...

Addition would then just be: `Point2D c = new Point2D(a.x + b.x, a.y + b.y);`

In 3d space I would create my own class, or an entirely different data structure depending on you actual problem.

Edit: I hope he has found a solution in the past 3 years..

Comment: This is one solution to the OP's problem, but not an answer to the OP's question.

Comment: @gh. I don't know if it's that black and white... it certainly seems to clearly answer the second part of the OP's question "Is there any way to do Vector manipulations (particularly addition) in Java?"

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there is a built-in way to do vector addition, however I've found [a series](http://www.developer.com/java/other/article.php/3750686/Vector-Addition-Math-for-Java-Game-Programmers.htm) describing how this could be done.

Answer (score 2):

Java3D has various forms of Vector classes (Vector3d, Vector3f, Vector4d, etc). Java3D, of course, is somewhat risky these days, though, as it's seemingly set for abandonment.

Comment: Java3D is definitely set for abandonment.  However, this is still a good answer, because you can easily just take "vecmath.jar" from Java3D and use the vector classes by themselves.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is old but maybe someone will find this useful:

There is also [Apache Commons Math](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/) which has a [Vector2D](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math4/geometry/euclidean/twod/Vector2D.html) class.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you'll have to write a library (or use a third-party library) in order to perform vector arithmetic.