# changing C vectors to Java

Tags: java, c, vector

There is a C code which I have to change it to Java. In this code there are a lot of vectors like Vector2 and Vector3. 
I know I can define arrays or lists for them in Java language But I want to ask is there any predefined structure or class in Java which work as the same as vector2 or vector3?

For example Point in java is like a vector2 which 2 double variable but you can't store any other data type in Point.

Comment: What is the signature of vector2 and vector3?

Comment: These are some samples of vector2 and vector3 which use double elements:
Vector2 v_north = { 1.0, 0.0 };
Vector3 v_target_tmp = {v_north.u, v_north.v, 1.0};

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is about vector math, you probably want to use a vector math library, e.g.

- javax.vecmath:
  http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/j2se/javase/technologies/desktop/java3d/forDevelopers/j3dapi/javax/vecmath/package-summary.html
- Pythagoras: https://github.com/samskivert/pythagoras

Otherwise, you may want to use java.util.ArrayList, which is the closest match for c++ stl vectors.  Don't use the java Vector class, it's only maintained for compatibility with older code.

For fixed size vectors, you may just want to use Java arrays (as suggested in a different answer).

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know vector math library has all such classes.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [java.util.ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html). It works well as a variable-length container. There's a java.util.Vector class, but it's better not to use that for [a variety of reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386275/why-is-java-vector-class-considered-obsolete-or-deprecated).

If you need to perform geometric operations on your vectors (addition, multiplication, projection, etc) then you will need to look at other options (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1632481/can-you-do-vector-addition-in-java-natively) for a start).

Comment: 1. The Vector class in Java resembles a List, that's not what the OP is looking for. 2. ArrayList is far better than Vector (but still not what the OP is looking for).

Comment: And how exactly do you know what the OP is looking for?

Comment: Well actually I'm starting to have doubts myself, since I saw "but you can't store any other data type in Point". Honestly I'm not sure what he wants anymore. Therefore, I removed my downvote but unfortunately I can't really upvote either.

Comment: As stated in Stefan Haustein's answer, java.util.Vector is still not a good idea.

Comment: Yeah, thanks for pointing that out. I didn't know that before you mentioned it.

Answer (score 0):

`Object[2]` is an array of 2 elements that will store any object reference.  Or there are several different List classes in java.util (not sure why so many are needed) that will store any object and are variable length.  To store, say, a `double` as an object so it can co-exist with other objects in an array, use `new Double(doubleValue)`.

Comment: Or, if the OP knows exactly which kind of object should be stored in the array, `SpecificClass[2]`

Comment: Always use Double.valueOf(doubleValue) -- new Double(doubleValue) will allocate new objects even for frequent values such as 0, 1, -1...